# Android URI of image/Video like "content://media/external/video/media/3032" can be different overtime

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, scoped-storage

I am working with scopedMedia storage and now getting the URI like this content://media/external/video/media/3032, I have to store them to upload on server. Now I am bit confused what if it could change after some time then it will be big issue in app.
So My question is content URI of image/video remain same or not?

Comment: If you take persistable uri permission then yes i think so. All has noting to do with scoped media storage whatever that would be.

Comment: Note that persistable `Uri` permissions are only possible for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and other Storage Access Framework APIs. If you are using anything else, you are at risk of losing access to the content identified by the `Uri`.